# Group by Specific month in SQL. For example group by month "november"

Tags: mysql, sql

basically there are three tables with the following schema:
[image: Schema details]
we are supposed to get average humidity of the states and country where month is November. it shows the following error where (state_weather_stats.record_date) shows following error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 8: Unknown column
> 'state_weather_stats.record_date' in 'HAVING clause'

if month() is supposed to return a number between 1 and 12, what is the error in the following code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

SELECT state.name || ' ' || country.name || ' ' ||
       AVG(state_weather_stats.humidity) || ' ' || CASE
         WHEN AVG(state_weather_stats.temperature) < 20 then
          'COLD'
         WHEN AVG(state_weather_stats.temperature) < 30 then
          'WARM'
         ELSE
          'HOT'
       END AS temp
  FROM country
 INNER JOIN state
    ON country.id = state.country_id
 INNER JOIN state_weather_stats
    ON state.id = state_weather_stats.state_id
 GROUP BY month(state_weather_stats.record_date)
HAVING month(state_weather_stats.record_date) = 11
 ORDER BY AVG(state_weather_stats.humidity) desc, state.name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate the creation of your string with the query that retrieves your averages.

You can:

- apply your `JOIN` operations first
- select your preferred month inside the condition of the `INNER JOIN`
- aggregate on the fields you are selecting ("*s.name*" and "*c.name*")
- use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to concatenate strings of your choice with the delimiter given as first input.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT s.name              AS state_name,
           c.name              AS country_name,
           AVG(w.humidity)     AS avg_humidity,
           AVG(w.temperature)  AS avg_temperature
    FROM       country             c
    INNER JOIN state               s 
            ON c.id = s.country_id   
    INNER JOIN state_weather_stats w
            ON s.id = w.state_id
           AND MONTH(w.record_date) = 11        
    GROUP BY s.name,
             c.name
)
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', state_name, 
                      country_name, 
                      avg_humidity,
                      CASE WHEN avg_temperature < 20 THEN 'COLD'         
                           WHEN avg_temperature < 30 THEN 'WARM'
                                                     ELSE 'HOT' END) AS temp
FROM cte
```